# Delphi equivalent code of a C code

Tags: c, delphi, delphi-2010, translation

I been a long time since I wrote a C code. Does anyone knows how to translate this piece of code to Delphi 2010?

```
char * pAlignedBuf = (char *) ((int(buf) + 7) & ~7);
```

where buf is `char * buf`.

I know that `char *` is `Pchar`, but I dont know what `&` and `~7`are.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&` is the bitwise `and` operator.

`~` id the bitwise unary `not` operator.

~7 is a number with all the lower 3 bits set to 0.

`& ~7` makes all the lower 3 bits 0 for whatever is on the left side.

The `(char *)` at the right of the assignment is a hard cast to `char *`

`int(buf)` is a hard cast of `buf` to integer.

That code can be written, in pascal, like this:

```
var pAlignedBuf: PChar;
pAlignedBuf := PChar((integer(Buf) + 7) and (not 7))
```

And it's a way to obtain an 8 byte aligned buffer from whatever `Buf` is. It works by incrementing the Buf with 7 and then clearing the lower 3 bits.

---

*Edit*

To be on the safe side, since Delphi 64 bit is somewhat around the corner, that code can be expressed as:

```
var pAlignedBuf: PChar;
pAlignedBuf := PChar(NativeUInt(Buf) + 7) and (not 7))
```

And for those that don't like bitwise logic-fu, it can be again re-written as:

```
var pAlignedBuf: PChar;
pAlignedBuf := PChar(((NativeUInt(Buf) + 7) div 8) * 8);
```

Comment: Note that D2007 and below Char is an AnsiChar and D2009 and above Char is an Unicode Char. Given that you try to work with aligned memory I can only assume you might want to use PByte or PAnsiChar instead of PChar. The only advantage of P(Ansi|Wide|)Char is that you can use the plus and minus operator to increment / decrement the pointer instead of using the pointer calculations like above.

Answer (score 4):

`&` is the binary "bitwise and" operator, which you write `and` in Delphi. `~` is unary "bitwise not" operator, which you write `not` in Delphi.

The translation is therefore

```
var
  PAlignedBuf: PChar;
begin
  pAlignedBuf := PChar((cardinal(buf) + 7) and not 7).
```

(Well, strictly speaking, the literal translation is `integer(buf)`, not `cardinal(buf)`, but I think `cardinal` is better. But I am not 100 % sure since I don't know the actual case.)

Answer (score 0):

`&` is the bitwise-and operation. Example: `0b0011 & 0b0110 == 0b0010`.
`~` is the bitwise-negation operation. Example: `~0b0111 == 0b1000` (assuming 4-bit numbers).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the casts are legal, the statement

```
char * pAlignedBuf = (char *) ((int(buf) + 7) & ~7);
```

puts in `pAlignedBuf` the address pointed to `buf` aligned to 8 bytes (last 3 bits set to 0).

```
     `buf`   `pAlignedBuf`
   0x...420    0x...420
   0x...421    0x...428
   0x...422    0x...428
...
   0x...427    0x...428
   0x...428    0x...428
...
   0x...429    0x...430
```